# QGIS 3.28.2 sending GIS project and keeping the symbology

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, style, save

I want to send someone a QGIS project. The symbology is always changing when the receiver opens the project. How can I save the symbology so that the style isn't changing all the time?

Comment: Style should be saved as part of the QGIS project and should stay the same each time the project is opened. Could you tell us more on how the style is defined in the project you need to share and in what format are the data. Also did you share the project AND the data or only the project because the data are accessible to all ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the layer then select properties

[image]

In the property dialog you select the "symbology tab" then click on style--> Save Style

[image]

Keep the default choices then choose save as GIS QML Style File.

You can then share your file with your colleague

[image]

When sharing the project with others, the style of the layers should not change.

***Note that the layer files i.e shapefile does not hold the style you have set.The styles are properties of the project***

If you want to apply the style on the layer again in a different computer, then use the same method but use "Load Style" and it will work

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. I will try it.

Comment: okay, it doesn't work. Do I have to reupload the style layer into the project?

Comment: That was for saving the style to QML format. If you want to apply the style on the layer again in a different computer, then use the same method but use "Load Style" and it will work.

Comment: @eva I have edited my response accordingly

Comment: thank you! so he has to upload every style of the layer?

Comment: it would be good to name the qml file with a meaningful name like the layer name, i.e. Water Body, roads, POI ....